# why button hide when panel is open in jqm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me why my button hide when I open panel.I already used data-display="overlay"..button should slide in left direction when panel is open and it come to original position when panel is closed.

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/1/

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left"  data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" data-display="overlay">
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <label class="testSuiteId">Test Suite</label>
        <div id="tree">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>


    </div><!-- /panel -->
<div class="main_cont">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

        <a href="#mypanel" data-role="button">open</a>


    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div class="cb"></div>




</div>




</div>
```

As written is documentation 
http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/FZQ8D/4/

#### HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left"  data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" data-display="push" >
        <!-- panel content goes here -->
        <label class="testSuiteId">Test Suite</label>
        <div id="tree">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /panel -->    
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#mypanel" data-rel="panel" class="ui-btn">open</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div class="cb"></div>   
</div>
```

#### Errors:

- First I have removed div with class name **main_cont**, data-role="page" div container can have only 3 kind of inner children: **data-role="header"**, **data-role="content"**, **data-role="footer"** and nothing else.
- I have removed **data-display="overlay"** attribute from panel widget and add **data-display="push"** attribute